# Angular.js dependency in Onsen UI

Tags: onsen-ui

I am new in Onsen UI and I wanted to develop an app using just HTML and CSS and later on I will integrate Backbone with it. I don't know Angular.js. I am making a Onsen project and just loading onsenui.js and not angular.js but I am getting an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined` .

So I wanted to know is Onsen UI has dependency on Angular? Can I make a Onsen project without Angular also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, AngularJS is a dependency for Onsen UI so it's required to use the `<ons-*` tags. AngularJS is used to defined the custom tags.

You can use the CSS components without AngularJS:
http://components.onsen.io/

You can use Backbone if you like, but you'll have to load AngularJS as well.

Comment: Doc says that Onsen UI 2 doesn't require Angular. I have tried onsen ui without angular (by deleting all angular files) and it worked, as long as I avoid onsen ui tags marked as angular directives.